# Pre trained vehicle detection from low altitude view

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo, object-recognition

[image: low altitude vehicles detection]

I have a very noob question. I need some solution to detect all vehicles in the video (or at least in the image).

I have tried YOLOv3, however, it cannot recognize cars from the top (like that in the photo). Thought it works perfect with street view images.

Any advices on what can I do to detect cars from the top?